# Creating an application that moves a collection files from one place to another using VB

Tags: vb.net, search, copy, unzip

So this is an application I have to create that moves files from one directory to another, both directories being specified by the user. It seems easy enough, but the problem is that there are millions of files that have to be searched through. These files are all named with 8 digits for example, "98938495.crt". The directory where all these files are has multiple folders. These folders within the main one are named with the first two digits of all the files that are in the folder. And then in that folder there are roughly ten zipped folders that contain 100,000 files each. The name of those folders are the minimum and maximum names of the files. For example, I go into the main folder, then click on the "90xx" folder. In that one there are 10 zipped folders which are named with the minimum and maximum names of the files, like "90000000_90099999.zip". That zip folder contains 100000 files. Now, this app is supposed to find all the files that the user inputs and then move them to a folder specified by the user. I have posted my code so far below, any help at all is greatly appreciate!!

FYI: The STID is the name of the file.

[GUI for the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z93Bq.png)

Edit: I realized there is no way to answer this question because there really isn't a question, just a broken app. Basically, how do i search for the items in the directory and then copy them into a new directory?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO


Public Class CertFinder

Private Sub SourceDirectoryTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SourceDirectoryTB.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub DestinationDirectoryTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DestinationDirectoryTB.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub SearchTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchTB.TextChanged


End Sub

Private Sub SourceButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SourceButton.Click

    Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        SourceDirectoryTB.Text = fbd.SelectedPath

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DestinationButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DestinationButton.Click

    Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        DestinationDirectoryTB.Text = fbd.SelectedPath
    End If

End Sub




Private Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    'Array of stids
    Dim stidsToFind As String()

    'get text in the searchTB textbox
    Dim searchTBText As String = Me.SearchTB.Text.Trim()

    'splits stids into seperate lines
    stidsToFind = searchTBText.Split(vbCrLf)

    'gets text from source directory text box
    Dim sourceDirectory As String = Me.SourceDirectoryTB.Text.Trim()

    'gets text from destination directory text box
    Dim destinationDirectory As String = Me.DestinationDirectoryTB.Text.Trim()

    Dim fullPathToFile As String = sourceDirectory

    'Go through each stid in the search text box and continue if nothing
    For Each stidToFind As String In stidsToFind

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stidToFind) Then
            Continue For
        End If


        'Find the first two digits of the stid
        Dim firstTwoDigitsOfSTID As String = stidToFind.Substring(0, 2)

        'In the specified directory, find the folder with the first two digits and "xx"
        fullPathToFile = fullPathToFile & "\" & firstTwoDigitsOfSTID & "xx"



        Dim allFileNames As String() = Nothing
        allFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.crt*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    Next

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Try
        If File.Exists(fullPathToFile) = False Then
            Dim FS As FileStream = File.Create(fullPathToFile)
            FS.Close()
        End If


        File.Move(fullPathToFile, destinationDirectory)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} moved to {1}", fullPathToFile, destinationDirectory)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist")

    End Try




    Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()

    'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
    Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(destinationDirectory)
    'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
    Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(stidsToFind)
    'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
    output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    ' 1. Get the names of each .zip file in the folder.
    ' 2. Assume that the .zip files are named as such <minimum STID>_<maximum STID>.zip
    ' 3. For each .zip file name, get the Minimum STID and Maximum STID values.
    ' 4. Check the range of 'stidToFind' against the STID ranges of each .zip file.
    ' 5. Once the .zip file is located, 
    '   a. Copy the .zip file to the local computer OR
    '   b. Just leave it where it is.
    ' 6. Unzip the file.
    ' 7. Create the full file name path. ../<stidToFind>.crt
    ' 8. Copy the file to the destination directory.
    ' 9. Delete the unzipped folder
    ' 10. Delete the .zip file (IF you've copied it to your local computer).








End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

1. In answer to the .ZIP unpacking, use the System.IO.Packaging (more can be found at [CodeProject - Zip Files Easy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28107/Zip-Files-Easy/))
2. Don't you think using a database would be easier to store that data?